# Connecting external monitor at 1440p to mid-2012 MBP 13"

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, resolution

Recently I bought Dell S2719DM monitor, which maximum resolution is 2560x1440. I'd like to use it with my mid-2012 13 inch MacBook Pro, so I got Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter - it uses HDMI 1.4 and supports 4K resolution, but when I connect my laptop via HDMI cable included to the monitor and this adapter, the maximum resolution available is 2048x1152. 
What's the problem here, should I buy better adapter? If so, what HDMI or DP version should I consider? Will [that adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HHLN2ZM/B/belkin-4k-mini-displayport-to-hdmi-adapter) work in 1440p with my computer?